# What are the final steps to complete the Linux Mint (Cinnamon) installation?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, system-installation, intel

I launched the Live "try out" version of Linux Mint after uninstalling Intel RST via Windows (a pop-up suggested this had to be disabled and I couldn't find an option to simply disable it). I finished the installation prompts for Linux, without error, but Windows is still the active OS. Can someone simplify the steps to change boot order or whatever needs to be done in order to remove Windows and have Linux on startup? I do NOT want a dual-boot. I want Linux Mint as my only OS. Thanks in advance!

Edit: There was no option to "replace Windows with Linux" during the installation process.

Comment: You'll probably want to open the partition software in the live USB/DVD (I don't have a VM set up for this, but it's probably GParted) and use that to remove all partitions, make a large single partition (for simplicity sake as this is your first steps into Linux) and then go ahead and install - the installer will format the drive for you. But, you'll want to remove any existing partitions first.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want Windows on the machine whatsoever, and you've disabled RST already, choose the 'wipe disk and install Linux Mint' option in the installer.